# rotated UITableView within UITableViewCell not showing where initWithFrame: says to

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I have a UITableViewController with a subclass of UITableViewCell with a UITableView in each cell. I have both UITableViews working just fine.  The problem comes when I rotate it.  If I set the frame of the tableViewInCell to a width larger than the height of the containing cell, then it goes heywire.  See below.

Width of tableView set to a value <= height of containing tableViewCell:

```
tableViewInCell = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 132, 132) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

[image: Width of tableView set to a value <= height of containing tableViewCell]

Width of tableView set to a value > height of containing tableViewCell:

```
tableViewInCell = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 132, 320) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

[image: Width of tableView set to a value > height of containing tableViewCell]

How do I get the tableViewInCell to fill the width of the containing UITableViewCell and not go heywire?

**UPDATE:**

```
tableViewInCell = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 132) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
```

[image: tableViewInCell = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 132) style:UITableViewStylePlain];]

**UPDATE 2:** Here is the method where I set up the tableViewInCell.

```
-(void)setupTableView {

tableViewInCell = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 132) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
[tableViewInCell setDelegate:self];
[tableViewInCell setDataSource:self];
tableViewInCell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI * .5);
[self addSubview:tableViewInCell];

}
```

Comment: what happens if you change (132, 320) to (320, 132)

Comment: See my screenshot update in the question.

Comment: Can you post some code on how did you rotate the table

Comment: posted the code for the setupTableView: method that gets called in the initWithStyle:reuseIdentifier: method.

Comment: does calling the new code you posted breaks the view?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. The only thing that changes is the height of the tableViewInCell.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12345/discussion-between-tarheel-and-omar-abdelhafith)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your current `setupTableView` to

```
-(void)setupTableView {
    tableViewInCell = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 132 , 320) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    tableViewInCell.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI * .5);
    tableViewInCell.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 132);
    [tableViewInCell setDelegate:self];
    [tableViewInCell setDataSource:self];
    [self addSubview:tableViewInCell];

}
```